# How to use format whitelist in QuillJS?

Tags: quill

I have looked around the [Quill documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/), GitHub topics, and here in Stack Overflow and I have been unable to find a simple example of using the [format](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/) attribute. I would like to limit my users so that they can only bold, italicize, underline, and hyperlink text.

From what I understand, this can be achieved with a format whitelist, but I have only been able to find examples regarding custom fonts or other more complex properties.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5):

I did some more digging around and found the answer. The following creates a Quill editor that allows only bold, italics, underline, and links. The list of allowed formats is just an array, and all [omitted formats](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/) will not be allowed in the editor, so they won't show up if a user pastes text.

```
var toolbarOptions = [['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],['link'],['clean']];
var formatWhitelist = ['bold','italic','link'];

var quill = new Quill('#notification-message', {
    scrollingContainer: 'true',
    theme: 'snow',
    formats: formatWhitelist,
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    }
});
```