# Why does Quill filter its content?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, quill, ngx-quill

When I use QuillJs to edit an existing HTML document, it removes the comments, indentations etc of the original HTML. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quill does not support arbitrary HTML. By default, anything that is not recognized will be converted (the `<strong>` tag to the `<b>` tag) when possible, or removed when not.

In [Quill configuration options](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#options), use the configuration named `formats`. The formats defined in this property will create a *whitelist*, where anything not in it will be filtered. A list of all formats can be found [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/#formats).

For more information, visit the following links:

- [Quill JavaScript Rich Text Editor restrict tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223982/quill-javascript-rich-text-editor-restrict-tags/52292057#52292057)
- [Suppress certain formats in Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328147/suppress-certain-formats-in-quill)
- [How to use format whitelist in QuillJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440583/how-to-use-format-whitelist-in-quilljs)

To add support for new formats you will need to create a new one. See the following links to find out how this can be done:

- [What, how and when to use static formats, formats and format on custom blot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366868/what-how-and-when-to-use-static-formats-formats-and-format-on-custom-blot/59382673#59382673)
- [Cloning Medium with Parchment](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/)
- [Parchment API](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#parchment--)
- [Native examples](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/formats)
- [A emoji blot example](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji/blob/master/src/format-emoji-blot.js)

As a tip, if you want to create Blot, and you want to allow it to be only edited or removed as a whole, set your Blot to be a child of [Embed](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#embed-blot).

### EDIT (DEC 20, 2019)

I forgot to say something: If you are pasting content to the editor, you better take a look at the [clipboard module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/).